# How to input decimal places in Textfield from MUI in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try to input with some decimal but I got this prompt message from my min-max value.

and this is my Textfied element

```
<TextField
  type="number"
  InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 36, max: 40 } }}
  onFocus={() => handleOnFocus('bodyTemp')}
  onChange={(e) => setBodyTemp(e.target.value)}
  value={bodyTemp}
 />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLhs5.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `step` attribute.

```
 <TextField
  type="number"
  step="any"
  InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 36, max: 40 } }}
  onFocus={() => handleOnFocus('bodyTemp')}
  onChange={(e) => setBodyTemp(e.target.value)}
  value={bodyTemp}
 />
```

Comment: Thanks I fix it by putting the step inside the in InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 36, max: 40, step: 'any' } }}